# How to validate two textbox at same time?

Tags: validation

Hi in my web application there are 3 textbox. Id, Name, and Date. User can search either by Id or by Name and Date. That is if user enter an Id and hit enter details are displayed. or if user enter Name and date and hit enter details are displayed. When user click submit it should validate in such a way if Name text box is empty and Date textbox contains some data it should show an "*" after empty textbox with validation summary having error. In the same way if Date text box is empty and Name contains some data it should show an "*" after empty textbox with validation summary having error. I am using server side validation methods for custom validation. Can any one help me with this?

Comment: Why you want to use custom validation, how abt using  a validation summary

Comment: You need more context.  Is this a web-app?  What tool stack?  In struts, this is trivial with commons-validator.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this link
http://authors.aspalliance.com/joteke/validationarticle1/article.aspx

or

You can try this one too

> 1. add two textboxes to your form (textBox1 and textBox2)
> 2. add a custom validator controls (CustomValidator1)
> 3. double click on the CustomValidator1 and create the
>      following:

```
private void CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(object source, System.Web.UI.WebControls.ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{

if(args.Value!=""&&TextBox2.Text=="")
{
args.IsValid = false;
}
else
{
args.IsValid = true;
}

}
```